# R how to wrap a function that uses tidyeval?

Tags: r, tidyeval

I have a function that uses tidyeval like `select_this` defined below. I have another function `wrapper_select_this` wrapping it, but I get the below error. Is there a simple way to adjust the `wrapper_select_this` to work (in this case: output the same as function `select_this`)?

```r
library(tidyverse)

z <- c("a", "b")
df <- data.frame(Z = 1:3, a = 1:3, b = 1:3)

select_this <- function(df, x){
  x_upper <- enexpr(x) %>% str_to_upper
  
  df %>%
    select(
      all_of(x_upper), all_of(x)
    )
}

wrapper_select_this <- function(df, x){
  df %>% select_this(x)
  
}

df %>% select_this(z)
#>   Z a b
#> 1 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3 3

df %>% wrapper_select_this(z)
#> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Column `X` doesn't exist.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I don't understand why you need the wrapper_select_this, when you are doing the same effort with `select_this`

Comment: This is for exercise/debugging sake . My actual wrapper has more operations in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `select_this()` to support quosures, you can then use `{{` to interface with it. In this case you can use `as_name()` to transform a potentially quosured symbol to a string:

```r
z <- c("a", "b")
df <- data.frame(Z = 1:3, a = 1:3, b = 1:3)

select_this <- function(df, x) {
  x_upper <- toupper(rlang::as_name(enquo(x)))

  df %>%
    select(all_of(x_upper), all_of(x))
}

df %>% select_this(z)
#>   Z a b
#> 1 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3 3
```

Then use `{{` to interface with it:

```r
wrapper_select_this <- function(df, x){
  df %>% select_this({{ x }})
}

df %>% wrapper_select_this(z)
#>   Z a b
#> 1 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3 3
```

I have to say I find it a bit confusing that you're selecting columns both by defused name and by the column names contained in the env-var of the same name.

Comment: Why not use `enexpr` in place of `enquo`? On your last note, I had objects SCALE_questions containg strings of scales of questions, and I wanted a function to select not only the questions, but also the SCALE_score sum of the questions based simply on the name of SCALE_questions. I agree it is confusing and I decided to simply add another variable to my function: SCALE. Now the function takes the SCALE name and the object containing the strings of questions (I did not want the object to contain the string of SCALE_score).

Comment: In snippets like this I use `enquo()` when possible even when not needed because it's easy to use `enexpr()` in places where `enquo()` would be appropriate. Also `{{` uses `enquo()` under the hood so even with `enexpr()` you might get quosures, which is easy to forget.